# Instantiating a field of an sObject with a string value passed through AJAX

Tags: ajax

I am trying to instantiate a sObject in my controller. The information that I am populating about it comes from my AJAX. Including the name of the field that I want to populate + its value.

So with that said the method that the AJAX is calling looks like this:

```
public static String updateInputField(Id objectkId, String objectFieldName, Integer objectFieldValue) {
        String errorMsg = 'testerror';
        Stock__c objectToUpdate = new Stock__c(Id=objecttId, objectFieldName=objectFieldValue);

return errorMsg;
}
```

However I get this error when trying to compile the code: **Invalid field stockFieldName for SObject Stock__c**

Any ideas why this is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this is to use sObject method `put`.

```
public static String updateInputField(Id objectkId, String objectFieldName, Integer objectFieldValue) {
    String errorMsg = 'testerror';
    Stock__c objectToUpdate = new Stock__c(Id=objecttId);
    objectToUpdate.put(objectFieldname,objectFieldValue);  // dynamic DML

    return errorMsg;
 }
```

There is a corresponding `sObject.get()`method for getting fieldvalues by fieldname.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I looked up the get(FieldName) method on salesforce and read through the examples but don't quite get it. How is it going to help me?

Comment: Look at my example with the "put" method

Comment: Okay I see how to populate the objectToUpdate with the put. But do I need the get() and where? I am already passing the objectFieldName through ajax right?

Comment: Nope. Get() was added to the answer purely for educational reasons